# How to create multiple SparkContexts in a console

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to create more than one SparkContext in a console. According to a post in [mailing list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Multiple-SparkContexts-in-same-Driver-JVM-td20037.html#a21454), I need to do SparkConf.set( 'spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts' , true), it seems reasonable but can not work. Can anyone have experience in this? thanks a lot:

bellow is that I do and the error message, I made that in a Ipython Notebook:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("spark://10.21.208.21:7077").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
conf.getAll()
[(u'spark.eventLog.enabled', u'true'),
 (u'spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts', u'true'),
 (u'spark.driver.host', u'10.20.70.80'),
 (u'spark.app.name', u'pyspark-shell'),
 (u'spark.eventLog.dir', u'hdfs://10.21.208.21:8020/sparklog'),
 (u'spark.master', u'spark://10.21.208.21:7077')]

sc1 = SparkContext(conf=conf.setAppName("app 1")) ## this sc success
sc1
<pyspark.context.SparkContext at 0x1b7cf10>

sc2 = SparkContext(conf=conf.setAppName("app 2")) ## this failed
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-e6dcca5aec38> in <module>()
----> 1 sc2 = SparkContext(conf=conf.setAppName("app 2"))

/usr/local/spark-1.2.0-bin-cdh4/python/pyspark/context.pyc in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc)
    100         """
    101         self._callsite = first_spark_call() or CallSite(None, None, None)
--> 102         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway)
    103         try:
    104             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

/usr/local/spark-1.2.0-bin-cdh4/python/pyspark/context.pyc in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway)
    226                         " created by %s at %s:%s "
    227                         % (currentAppName, currentMaster,
--> 228                             callsite.function, callsite.file, callsite.linenum))
    229                 else:
    230                     SparkContext._active_spark_context = instance

ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=app 1, master=spark://10.21.208.21:7077) created by __init__ at <ipython-input-21-fb3adb569241>:1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a PySpark-specific limitation that existed before the `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` configuration was added (which relates to multiple SparkContext objects within a JVM).  PySpark disallows multiple active SparkContexts because various parts of its implementation assume that certain components have global shared state.

Comment: According to your comments here https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3121, it seems that spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts was added as an exception (to support testing) and that usage of multiple contexts is discouraged, since SPARK-2243 is still not resolved. Looking at SparkContext code, there can only be one active SparkContext, so this is not just PySpark-specific limitation. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @pzecevic, that's correct: technically, Spark only supports a single active SparkContext.  PySpark always had an error message for this, but Scala/Java Spark wouldn't prevent you from creating multiple active contexts even though it wasn't officially supported.  Multiple active contexts might work, _by accident_, in some cases, so we added the new configuration as a temporary escape hatch and for use in testing; users generally should not enable that flag, since it only disables the error-checking and doesn't actually enable proper support for multiple contexts.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. It seems to me then that your answer is a bit misleading... This is not a PySpark-specific limitation and charles.li shoudn't try to use multiple contexts at all (until proper support is added)

Comment: In java/Scala this is possible, using multiple classloaders. Each class loader will create its own version of the classed it loads (statics and all). E.g jobserver does this : https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server/src/spark.jobserver/JobManagerActor.scala#L91.  So this is possible a limitation for pyspark, but can be worked around in java

Answer (score 3):

I was hoping previous spark context be stopped and closed by calling close() stop() and the new one can be recreated, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

My way:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
try:
    sc.stop()
except:
    pass
sc=SparkContext('local','pyspark')
'''
your code
'''
sc.stop()
```

Comment: You should use `except NameError:` instead. What if you get a totally different exception and silently bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

Run the bellow function before creating a new context

```
def kill_current_spark_context():
    SparkContext.getOrCreate().stop()
```