# I can't create multiple sparkContexts in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, multiple-instances

I use the commands

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("spark://10.21.208.21:7077").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
conf.getAll()
```

[image]
Cannot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple SparkContexts in a console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259756/how-to-create-multiple-sparkcontexts-in-a-console)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark multiple contexts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827333/spark-multiple-contexts)

Answer (score 0):

**`spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts`** option exists only for internal test cases. its not for external use and it is not supposed to be used in user programs.