# Spark Resource Allocation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We are evaluating Apache Spark (pySpark) as a framework for our machine learning pipeline.
 
It consists of (on a high level) two steps:

1. A pre-processing step (as we are working with audio data, sub-steps are for example computation of power spectrum) which is more optimized for running on CPU nodes.
2. There is a training step, where the model gets build and which is rather optimized for GPU nodes. We would like to distribute the work in such a way, that the first step (data pre-processing) gets run on a CPU cluster and the second step (model training) gets run on a GPU cluster without having to manually intervene between step 1 and 2.

Questions:

1. Is Spark the right place to organize the handling of different clusters, or would it have to be done somewhere else (e.g. in the Mesos level)
2. If Spark is the right place, how do we organize it with Spark so that the first steps runs on a CPU cluster and the second step runs on a GPU cluster?

My initial idea was to create multiple SparkContext, but this seems to be discouraged, e.g. here: [How to create multiple SparkContexts in a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259756/how-to-create-multiple-sparkcontexts-in-a-console)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Spark has a standalone scheduler, so you wouldn't need Mesos. You seem to be mixing the development aspect of Spark code with the cluster maintenance.

Comment: @cricket_007: Thanks for your comment. Mesos was just an example. The main question for us is how we can distribute our work amongst the resources, i.e. model training to the GPU and pre-processing to the CPU.

Comment: Does Spark need to be the full workflow? You could output a file onto disk using one Spark job, then another process (doesn't need to be Spark, since I'm not aware of Spark on GPU) could read those files.

Comment: It is not a must, but would ease things, as the researcher just defines all the elements of a job and everything else is handled. Do you know any other framework that would provide such capabilities?

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible with Spark, I've simply  never tried running On GPU (or used Tensorflow) but that's where I'd look first, personally