# cannot run multiple contexts at once

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark (Python- 3.6.2), when i started spark context with the following code it is throwing exception.

Can any one faced this kind of issue earlier?
I am attaching below screenshot for reference

[image: Cannot run multiple context]

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Spark does not support it won't support multiple `SparkContexts`. For reference, corresponding JIRA ([SPARK-2243](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243)) has been resolved as Won't Fix.

There is JVM specific `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` used for testing which was never supported in Python (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260286) and [quoting Josh Rosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259756/how-to-create-multiple-sparkcontexts-in-a-console/28260286#comment45355828_28260286):

> Multiple active contexts might work, by accident, in some cases, so we added the new configuration as a temporary escape hatch and for use in testing; **users generally should not enable that flag, since it** only disables the error-checking and **doesn't actually enable proper support for multiple contexts**.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one Spark Context and when you open the shell, the context gets created for you so you don't need to create it. If you write a stand alone application then you do have to create your own context. This is for the RDD API.

If you use DataFrames or Datasets, then you can have multiple Spark Sessions, they will share the same context but will give you independent views.